# Ionic Vue application keeps giving me CORS errors, while the server is accessible

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, vuejs3

I have made a apllication in CodeIgniter 4 and an app in Ionic / Vue3. Now when I deploy my CI4 application to my webserver and I try to login with my Ionic app it does not work. I keep getting CORS error back. I did extensive testing on my webserver and I'm sure that my server is correctly configured. There is no CORS issue when I try to do Cross Origin requests outside of my ionic vue3 app, but when i use the app it gives me the error. Preflight i get 200 back, but the rest is CORS error still.

When I switch the address of the Ci4 application to my local webserver it does work. I'm very confused. Can someone help me out here?

https://imgur.com/a/10fpCQd

https://i.imgur.com/46EmzXq.png

Maybbe I need to do something with the ionic app to make this work? Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic serve the application code from a different location than the one you have in your browser.
You need on the server side app to authorize CORS for

```
  'capacitor://localhost',
  'ionic://localhost',
  'http://localhost',
  'http://localhost:8080',
  'http://localhost:8100'
```

with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (please select the origins according to your case) you may not need all this origins.

Look the Ionic documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors to select the right origins.

Comment: I did add just the wildcard * so that every connection is accepted but that didn't seem to do the trick, i'm pulling my hairs here i'm not understanding why the preflight options does get accepted but the rest of the call is not